# What actually happens when a method is deprecated?

Tags: xcode, methods

This may seem a dumb question but perhaps someone can explain in simple terms what happens when you have deprecated methods "hanging around" like didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation for example.  I get warnings when I build but the app still runs.  Do the methods just not get called?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deprecate means "please don't". (It is literally from a Latin verb that means "ask not to.") That's *all* it means. It is just a marking in the API.

So as long as something is in a deprecated state, it is usually usable along with a warning.

But then you have to think *why* something is deprecated. Deprecation is often a prelude to eventual withdrawal in a future version. So it is wise to start migrating your code to whatever the new thing is, so that you are future-proof. Otherwise you can be caught with your pants down having to change everything in a hurry when your code completely breaks because the deprecation becomes an error.

---

The question "do the methods not get called" can be a tricky one. There's no hard and fast rule, but sometimes what happens is that there are two ways to do something, the deprecated way and the new way; in that case, Apple often sets things up so that *if* you do things the new way, then yes, your older methods are not called. I'm talking here about delegate methods of various kinds; if you adopt the new delegate methods, the old delegate methods stop working.